# openpyxl format worksheet for printing?

Tags: openpyxl

Using python3 with openpyxl. Is it possible to format a worksheet for (paper) printing? i.e. I would need to change the excel defaults to print two-sided, landscape orientation, print the entire workbook, etc. etc. etc. so I could just open the excel file and hit print.

Simple yes or no answer is fine, I saw there are some methods under the worksheet class called e.g. 'A3' or 'Executive' which in theory should correspond to paper sizes but they seem to be string values of integers?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, this possible.

This is a quite valid question and precise enough to be answered.

In the docs, there is this section:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/page.html#PrintPageSetup

---

**Programmatically define the data:**

You can customize your XLSX by extending their class PrintPageSetup, passing your values like:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
ws.title = "Your Tab Title"

# Printer Settings
ws.page_setup.orientation = ws.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
ws.page_setup.paperSize = ws.PAPERSIZE_A3

# Property settings
wsprops = ws.sheet_properties

wsprops.tabColor = "1072BA"
wsprops.filterMode = False
wsprops.pageSetUpPr = PageSetupProperties(fitToPage=True, autoPageBreaks=False)
wsprops.outlinePr.summaryBelow = False
wsprops.outlinePr.applyStyles = True
```

---

**Fill data into a prepared template:**

Also, if you prefer, you can prepare your document in Excel, save it as a template and then open it via openpyxl and dynamically add your actual data.

This is outlined in the docs as well:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
print wb2.get_sheet_names()
['Sheet2', 'New Title', 'Sheet1']
```

Answer (score 1):

This question really is too broad. In Excel there are many settings related to printing but you should probably look at the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/print_settings.html

Comment: Yeah the printing support is really limited. I need to print 1-sided 8"x14" landscape with all rows fit to the page. I'm not skilled enough at Python yet to contribute to a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like you want access to some of the stuff the printer driver manages. This can't be done from Python. Otherwise look at the `page` module in `openpyxl.worksheet`. See 18.3.1.63 pageSetup (Page Setup Settings) in the specification.